# Force Coefficient to be Negative in R lm

Tags: r, regression, lm

I want to force one of the coefficients in my model to be less than or equal to zero.

The nnls package allows you to set all coefficients equal to or greater than zero, but I'm at a loss as to how to specify a specific coefficient to be less than zero.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't have much experience with constrained regression, but my first thought would be to change the sign of the corresponding variable in your data. Then the >= 0 constraint should achieve your aim (although you will have made interpreting your model more convoluted).

Answer (score 6):

The function `nnnpls` in [the same package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nnls/index.html) is "an implementation of least squares with non-negative and non-positive constraints".

Its third argument, `con`, allows one to specify which coefficients should be non-positive:

> numeric vector of length `m` where element `i` is negative if and only if element
>   `i` of the solution vector `x` should be constrained to non-positive, as opposed to
>   non-negative, values.

Comment: Would you mind showing an example? I'm a little confused by the help page for nnpls.

Comment: Nothing like good old-fashioned RTFM, eh?  :-) . Tho' I have to admit it's not always obvious which *packages* to look into in the first place.  Here's a plug for the `sos` package, which does a pretty good job of seeking out tools and packages for you.

Comment: @BurtonGuster: The manual has the following example: `nnnpls(A,matdat[,i],con=c(1,-1,1))`. The first two arguments are exactly as you'd supply to `nnls()` and the third one is as explained in the paragraph I've quoted in my answer.

Comment: +1 Seconded.  This is a good, and fairly fast package for such calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Package ic.infer maybe suitable for this task.

From package vignette:
"In linear models and multivariate normal situations, prior information in linear inequality
form may be encountered, or linear inequality hypotheses may be subjected to
statistical tests. R package ic.infer has been developed to support inequality-constrained
estimation and testing for such situations."